# Entity Framework migrations adds properties of subclasses

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In a c# project, I have a DbContext that references entities of my domain model.
When I create the migration code with the

> add-migration MySetup

command, Entity framework (I use version 6.1 and SqlServer) not only creates migrations for the defined entities, but also adds properties of subclasses (even when they are in a different namespace and not used in the DbContext).

Example:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   ...
}

class User
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

And at a different place I have a class that is not used in the Context

```
class UserExtended : User
{
   public string AdditionalPropertyNotForEF { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Then the Migration class created with add-migration looks like

```
CreateTable(
   "dbo.User",
   c => new 
   {
      Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
      AdditionalPropertyNotForEF = c.String()
   }) ...
```

Comment: Use `[NotMapped]` attribute on the properties you want EF to ignore

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I would use the NotMapped property to ignore specific properties on my domain entity, but not on a totally different class that has no relation to the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known behavior of EF6 entity type discovery process, explained in the [Type Discovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_0) section of the documentation:

> If your types participate in an inheritance hierarchy, it is enough to define a `DbSet` property for the base class, and **the derived types will be automatically included, if they are in the same assembly as the base class.**

I agree that this is counterintuitive behavior (it has been fixed in EF Core), but this is how it is. So either don't inherit entity types, or exclude derived non entity types with `[NotMapped]` data annotation or `Ignore` fluent API.